# Sweet Alert, but buttons are disabled for the first few seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer, sweetalert2

I am creating a Sweet Alert that displays a very important message, and I don't want the user to dismiss it without reading.

So to emphasize the importance of the message, I would like to make the OK button disabled for (let's say...) 5 seconds, so the user must wait at least that before dismissing the alert.

A visible timer would be sweet too. I am using AngularJS in my application.

I could easily make a custom modal as an alert for this purpose, but the reason I want to use Sweet Alert is because it's already being used all over my application and I don't want to break the pattern.

Comment: Could you add an example of your code?

Comment: Where are you currently stuck at?

Comment: I assume you're looking for a complete solution.

Comment: There isn't much to say about my code. I just want to trigger a Sweet Alert with plain text that works as described. @LazioTibijczyk, I can work with starting point ideas. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this using what's available in [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) already. As mentioned in the other answer by Joseph, you should set the following sweetalert2 properties to false to avoid the user to dismiss the modal:

```
allowOutsideClick: false,
allowEscapeKey: false,
```

You can then hide the confirm button when the swal is shown:

```
onOpen: () => {
  swal.showLoading()
  ....
}
```

and then show again the confirm button after some time using a `setTimeout`:

```
onOpen: () => {
  swal.showLoading()
  setTimeout(() => { swal.hideLoading() }, 5000)
}
```

The full code of the swal is then:

```
swal({
  title: 'Please read this message!',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false, 
  onOpen: () => {
    swal.showLoading()
    setTimeout(() => { swal.hideLoading() }, 5000)
  },
}).then((result) => {
  if (!result.dismiss) {
     console.log('user read the important message')
  }
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code is what you are looking for

```
var h = 1;

function run(){
  if(h==1){
    swal('hello','warning', {button: {closeModal: false}, closeOnEsc: false, closeOnClickOutside: false}).then(nnn => {if(h==1){
      run();
    }else{
      swal.close();
    }});
    setTimeout(function(){ h = 0;}, 5000);
  }
}

run();
```

I'm sure that there are better ways to write this but that has worked for me, just set the timeout timer to whatever duration you want it to stay open.

Comment: Sweet Alert has the config options `closeOnClickOutside` and `closeOnEsc`. Setting both to false does lock the browser.

Comment: I added some changes to the code so it prevents the user from exiting for 5 seconds, but I can't find a way to get a timer into the actual modal window.